# Compute $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}n$, I am trying to compute

a) $\lim\limits{\inf(a_{n})}$

b) $\lim\limits{\sup(a_{n})}$

c) $\inf\{a_{n}\}$

d) ${\sup(a_{n})}$

My work:

a) $\lim\limits{\inf(a_{n})}=-\infty$

b) $\lim\limits{\sup(a_{n})}=+\infty$

c) $\inf\{a_{n}\}=-\infty$

d) ${\sup(a_{n})}=+\infty$

I find it hard work and results formally prove that these results only the intuition

Comment: Your answers look right. Justifying your infimum and supremum should not be hard. What are your definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$?

Comment: Start with the $\sup$ and $\inf$ first. For example, $\sup \{ a_n \}$ is an upper bound for $a_n$. So it must be $\geq$ all $a_n$. So choose specific $n$ that show why the answer must by $+ \infty$.

Comment: Many of the ideas that I suggested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/138931/12042) to your earlier question can be applied to this problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help you justify why the supremum is $+\infty$ and leave the part about infimum to you.

> Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R$. We say that the $\sup A=+\infty$ if $A$ is not bounded above.

**Claim:** $\{a_n\}_{n \geqslant 1}$ is not bounded above.

Let $b \in \Bbb R^+$.  Consider $\lfloor b \rfloor +i$, where $i=1$ if $\lfloor b\rfloor$ is odd and $i=2$ if $\lfloor b\rfloor$ is even. Look at the definition of  $\lfloor b \rfloor$: $$b-1\lt\lfloor b \rfloor \le b$$

So, $b \lt\lfloor b \rfloor +1 \leq \lfloor b \rfloor +i$ for our choices of $i$. Can you show that $a_{\lfloor b \rfloor+i}= \lfloor b \rfloor +i$?

> So, you have found a $n$ such that $b \lt a_n$. So, is $b$ an upper bound? What do you conclude?

Comment: @DanieldelCarmen I can help you about the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ if only I know your deefinitions. So, please add them in. Regards,